# What gets passed to the .map() iterator function on an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I have a function that takes in an array of objects and a string, which represents a property. The function should return an array containing that property from each object.

Here is my sample code:

```
function pluck(array, property) {
    var newArr = [];
    array.map(function(paints){
       return newArr.push(paints[property]); 
    });
    return newArr;
}
```

This returns a new array and it works. But when the function is taking in an array of objects as one of the arguments...what gets passed to the anonymous iterator function in the map method? The value of the key?

How would it iterate over an array of objects using the map method?

Comment: Map function isn't used properly here.

Comment: map will actually make a new array for you so you don't need the newArr and the push. you're treating map as `forEach` which it isn't. the lambda in map gets passed every element in the array in sequence the result is an array with elements of whatever the lambda returned on each call.

Comment: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - `(value, index, array) => new value at index`

Comment: @pvg Got it. I understand how I was using it incorrectly. But if the element in the array is itself an object, what gets passed to the iterated function. For example, if I was an array like [ 1, 2, 3 ] it would the element, but what if it's [ {color: 'blue'} ]? Would 'blue' be what is then passed on the argument of the iterator function?

Comment: nope, it would just be the object you have defined by the { }. it's always the element of the array and the element of the new array is whatever you return. that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on your question explain what is happening in your code.

When you call map on an array, the mapping function is provided with 3 arguments, which are used always, sometimes and rarely in that order.

```
const result = items.map(function(element, index, items) {
    // do the mapping
});
```

The function is called for each element of the original array `items` in turn, and the result of the function placed in the same index position of the `result` array.

The function arguments are:

- element - this is the current element from the array
- index - the current index
- items - the original array on which map was called

Your pluck function could be written as:

```
function pluck(arr, prop) {
    return arr.map(item => item[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Please explain the answer here as well since otherwise this would be an incomplete answer